# How to solve problems with array size that will not fit in main memory?

Tags: java, memory, dynamic-programming, edit-distance

Given two Array.
A = [1,3,4,2,5,6] B = [3,4,6,5,7]
we have to remove 3,1,2,6 and Insert 6,7 to make A equal to B.

we can delete and insert any element at anywhere from first array and make that array same as second array. Output is Minimum Number of elements required to be insert in first array.

```
constraints:
1 <= First Array Size <= 10^5
1<= Second Array SIze <= 10^5
1 <= firstarray[i] <= 10^9
1 <= secondarray <= 10^9
```

second array consist of distinct element.

Note : it is same as edit distance but here our constraints are 10^5.
Allocating two long array of 10^5 worked fine in my system. But for DP a 2d array of 10^5 and 10^5 gave outofmemoryerror.
I understand the maximum array size is size of int and also memory given.
Please explain how much memory allocated for heap and stack.
How to generally solve problems with big inputs like the ones that could not fit in memory in java?
Some code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: There are parameters to the ``java`` command that increase the size of memory allocated to java.

Comment: For the largest arrays, since you don't have to return such an array, but merely the number of elements to be inserted, you should be able to keep the arrays on the disk, or write them as such using a BufferedWriter, and access them in parts. Yes, this would take longer than it would if you could keep them in-memory, but it would be possible.

Comment: For this problem, You don't need to allocate any arrays, you should just count the elements that need to be added.

Comment: You may not actually need all 10^5 rows in memory at once.  See [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (specifically, the heading "Iterative with two matrix rows").